# wamp/localhost htaccess - bad flag delimiters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to migrate my testing site, locally.

I am running *WAMP* with:

- Apache 2.2.22
- Php 5.3.13

I have added to hosts file:

> 127.0.0.1             local.testsite.com

I have added to httpd-vhosts.conf (and included it in httpd.conf):

```
<Directory C:\wamp\www\testsite>
Order Deny,Allow   
Allow from all 
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>   
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\testsite" 
ServerName local.testsite.com 
</VirtualHost>
```

And rewrite_module is ON.

I am getting the following error in my local apache error log:

> [Sun Oct 26 09:24:17 2014] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1]
>   C:/wamp/www/testsite/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters,
>   referer: http://local.testsite.com/

This is my htaccess file (which worked on my external server):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^dashboard/$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^dashboard$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [NE,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas what could be the problem with my local wamp setup?

Thanks.

Comment: `"I am trying to migrate my testing site, locally"` - Are you migrating from a Linux Apache Server to a WAMP? If that's the case, make sure the line ending is in DOS/Windows style. If you are seeing it in Notepad, it should be visually obvious; other editors like Notepad++ don't show the visual difference but only show it in the status bar.

Comment: yeah, I had removed a load of blank lines from the file (just to make it look better) and that was the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had removed a ton of blank lines from the file (for aesthetic purposes only), when I undid this the htaccess file worked perfectly.